# Object value changing

Tags: c#

I am facing an issue while maintaining object's state.

I have a struct as follows;

```
public struct myStruct
{
    public String ViewType;
    public object objCB;
}
```

// Usage of struct type in the program

```
List<myStruct> mylist; //Global list

myStruct mystr; //Global struct object
```

In one of the event functions I am filling this struct object as follows;

```
private void onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mystr = new MyStruct();
    mystr.objCB = sender; //filling object value in struct object
}
```

Then in another method I am inserting this struct object in a list:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    mystr.ViewType = (rbLine.IsChecked == true) ? "SingleLine" : "Area";
    mylist.Add(mystr);
}
```

The problem is, that my previous `objCB` value in list is changed whenever  `onClick event` is been called (reason could be I am having reference of `sender object` in `list`).

I tried cloning an object with `MemberWiseCopy`, but it is still giving same problem.

How can I tackle with this problem?

Comment: you mean you do not want the objCB change AFTER you added the object to the list?

Comment: By the way: you shouldn't have mutable structs. Why is it a struct anyway? I've hardly ever seen a really good use case for a struct.

Comment: My previous objCB value is getting changed with the latest one.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger I am using struct as I have few other attributes in it as well. I could have opted for class but found struct is also fine in this case.

Comment: Change it to a class.  Its not correct to use a struct for this.

Comment: you shouldn't call an empty constructor for initializing a struct.

Comment: Using class will solve my problem?? @afrogonabike

Comment: It may do, but even if it doesn't its not correct to use a struct for this.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is `object` the most special type of `objCB`?

Comment: No. Actually it's a different project's class which sender refer to. I tried using that class as data type instead of object but it didn't work either. @Codor

Comment: Using class also gives same problem. And I used struct as I wanted value type instead of ref type class @afrogonabike

Comment: Why do you want value type?  Read the advice page i linked above.  You don't meet the criteria for using a struct.

Comment: I've just tried your code and it doesn't do what you say it does.  I don't have all references changed in the list, it just adds the last myStruct.

Comment: It does for me.. You might b missing something bro @afrogonabike

Comment: maybe but I'm not convinced.  When you call List.Add with a struct it creates a copy of that struct.  Therefore changing anything in the struct you passed in will not affect the value in the list.  This is how structs work.  Its therefore not possible for what you see to be happening.  is there more to your code that you're not posting?

Answer (score 0):

Declare static variable obj,

```
Object obj;
```

Update onclick event to,

```
private void onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   obj=sender;
}
```

Save action,

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myStruct mystr=new myStruct();//local variable
    mystr.objCB = obj;
    mystr.ViewType = (rbLine.IsChecked == true) ? "SingleLine" : "Area";
    mylist.Add(mystr);
    objCB=null;
}
```

Comment: This will work but the original code works too so i think there's more to this

Answer (score 0):

Your code works.  I've created this:

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public String ViewType;
    public object objCB;
}
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<MyStruct> mylist = new List<MyStruct>(); //Global list

   MyStruct mystr; //Global struct object

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonBase1_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mystr = new MyStruct();
        mystr.objCB = sender; //filling object value in struct object
    }


    private void Save_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mylist.Add(mystr);
    }
}
```

I have three buttons that connect to ButtonBase1_OnClick and a save button.  When I click button1 save button2 save button3 save I get three mystruct objects in the list with a reference to button1, button2 and button3.  The only way I can think that you'd get the failure you describe is with the following code:

```
public class MyStruct
{
    public String ViewType;
    public object objCB;
}
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<MyStruct> _mylist = new List<MyStruct>(); //Global list

    MyStruct _mystr = new MyStruct(); //Global struct object

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonBase1_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _mystr.objCB = sender; //filling object value in struct object
    }


    private void Save_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _mylist.Add(_mystr);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know my code works. I need solution now.. By the way thanks for confirmation bro..

Comment: I can't give you a solution to a problem you don't have.  There must be something else in your code that is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You are using the same object reference for all the items, so it will change the old values too to the latest one.

As you are encompassing filling values to two event-handlers, so you have a problem of declaring the variable, which is why you have declared it outside of all.

As you are simply adding the item to the end of the list, so best would be to :

```
private void onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        mylist.Add(new myStruct(){objCB = sender});
}

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        myStruct lastItem = mylist.Last();
        lastItem.ViewType = (rbLine.IsChecked == true) ? "SingleLine" : "Area";
}
```

.... EDIT after comment ....

Add a new attribute to the struct as `bool AddedStatus`. Default value would be false. Change this attribute to true after btnSave_Click is finished processing.

Inside your `onClick`, fetch last item from list and check it's `AddedStatus` value, and remove this item if it has value of `False`.

```
private void onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        myStruct lastItem = mylist.Last();
        if(myStruct != null && myStruct.AddedStatus == false)
            mylist.Remove(lastItem);

        mylist.Add(new myStruct(){objCB = sender, AddedStatus = false});
}

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        myStruct lastItem = mylist.Last();            
        lastItem.ViewType = (rbLine.IsChecked == true) ? "SingleLine" : "Area";
        lastItem.AddedStatus = true;
}
```

Comment: but I want that list to be filled by that object only if user click on Save button so I am filling list in btnSave_Click @AnjumSKhan

Comment: I have few other attributes of objects which need to be assigned using onChanged EventArgs. That's why I am initializing struct inside onChanged event. I apologize as I posted few attributes in main question which I found necessary to be posted.

Comment: @Gvs13 see my edited answer, this is best way to go as it is used by DataGrid for its new row added at the bottom.

Comment: It would be interesting to know why you need to store the original "sender" which I presume is a button.  This could perhaps highlight a design issue and there may be a better solution so you don't need to do this in the first place. @Gvs13

Comment: The other thing I'm a little confused by is that there is nothing wrong with the original code.  It works for me.  When you call new myStruct you create a new reference, the reference is stored in myStr - on save that reference is added to the list.  Later updating myStr to a new reference will not change it in the list.  Its not a reference to a reference.

Comment: but that is happening which confusing me too.